# Vista Protegida en Excel con GX 9

Tags: excel, genexus

Estoy generando archivos Excel desde GX9 - java. 
La versión Excel es 2013, Win 8. Si son generados en mi pc, todos los archivos Excel, se abren con "Vista Protegida" nivel rojo.
En la misma aplicación existen otros procedimientos que generan planillas Excel y no tienen este inconveniente.
El proceso de codificación es el mismo en todos:

```
&ExcelDoc.UseAutomation = 0
&ExcelDoc.Open(&Path)

Do 'CheckStatus'
&ExcelDoc.Clear()
&ExcelDoc.AutoFit = 1
```

... código de listado

```
&ExcelDoc.Cells(&Fila, &Columna).Color = 55
&ExcelDoc.Cells(&Fila, &Columna).Bold = 1
&ExcelDoc.Cells(&Fila, &Columna).Size = 14
```

...

```
&ExcelDoc.Save()
Do 'CheckStatus'
&ExcelDoc.Close()
```

Ya probé el tema de la "Configuración del centro de confianza" de Excel, pero nada.
Alguien tiene alguna idea qué puede ser? o les ha pasado algo similar?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Este problema también lo tengo y se debe a la versión del excel que tengo contra la versión del compilador que uso para la Gx9 (.NEt v1.1.4322). Pero en mi caso es aun peor, cuando exporto un archivo buguea la aplicación y debo forzar el cierre, buscar el proceso de excel en el administrador de tareas y finalizarlo. Con ello hecho puedo abrir los reportes en desarrollo. Pero en produccion no pasa esto, los clientes tienen winXp y office 2010. Espero mi experiencia te guíe en algo.

Comment: Maria Jose, hemos visto que tienes dos usuarios creados. Para juntarlos en uno solo, has de pulsar en [Contacto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) y en el formulario seleccionar "Necesito combiar perfiles de usuario". Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

He tenido problemas similares.
Usando Genexus X también.
Da el mismo error si en lugar de "abrir" el archivo desde el navegador, primero lo "bajan" al disco duro y luego lo abren desde la carpeta DOWNLOAD?
A mi con ese cambio de procedimiento se me solucionaron muchos problemas que me sucedian con diferentes versiones de Office.
La otra prueba para mi es ver que sucedia al usar LibreOffice u otro software para abrir el archivo, y el mismo SIEMPRE se abria sin problemas.
Solo para descartar que el problema sea "EL ARCHIVO GENERADO" o sea "MS OFFICE".